# Win+Number sometimes doesn't properly render preview above the taskbar

Tags: taskbar, windows-11, intel-graphics, windowing

I am accustomed to switching windows on Windows 11 using the Win+Number shortcut. When there are multiple instances of the same app open, a preview usually opens, where pressing the same number again will allow you to switch between the instances.

[image: working preview]

However, on my machine, **sometimes** the preview isn't rendered and the mechanism is broken. Sometimes it does work.
[image: broken preview]

As you can see, instead of a proper preview, there's just a gray box.

This happens on my Asus gaming Laptop that has an i9-12900H and 3070Ti. My windows 11 is fully updated and all drivers are up to date too. Graphics on the system seems fine otherwise.

To exit this weird state, I either Alt+Tab or Win+Number again.

I couldn't find relevant information online and I was wondering if anyone has any clue whats happening?

Comment: Does this gray window always appear on the same application, or for all of them? Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: @harrymc haven't tried on safe mode. this happens for a few applications, e.g. the multi VScode instances and the multiple Terminal instances

Comment: Please try it in Safe mode.

Comment: the feature is aero Peek, for better googling. I did find one fix: Do you have HDR enabled on any monitor(s)? Open display settings, and make sure Use HDR under "Windows HD Color" is turned off, but also click "Windows HD Color Settings" and make sure Use HDR is turned off for each monitor there as well